# How can i get a m3u8 chunk with the help of php to refresh it in video player source after it expires

Tags: javascript, php, html, m3u8

This is an example of a player playing m3u8
widestream.io/live-72

What i have is this for my website you can have a look at codes here:
http://fls-edge.com/fls-live-blog/radiant/radiant.html

You have to inspect element or CTRL+U to view the codes as it's all html and javascipt

i can't post my html here i tried but only half of it appeared and the rest disappeared

I tried the m3u8 chunks of live stream in free radiant player as well as every m3u8 player it works but m3u8 expires in 10 minutes and after every 10 minutes i have to manually inspect the element and re-insert in my video player source and the m3u8 looks like this

http://cdn.widestream.io:8081/wideedge/lehruwf/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9My8xMS8yMDE3IDU6NTY6NTQgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1CNEJsbkdmQnpFUFhDNjVDNHV5dHV3PT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTIw

This entire link can be used as source in JW live stream players.

Is there a possible way in php to get the following link whenever a user refreshes the page he sees a fresh m3u8 inside the video player.

My whole question is about web scraping and fetching the particular link from website and inserting that link in my player within my website player in hls:'.m3u8' with php curl or javascript any solution would be appreciable.

Comment: Correct code example indentions

Comment: I corrected the code can you please have alook at my question again.Thanks

Comment: Hey, tell me please , did you find a solution how to grab **wmsAuthSign** link for personal usage . ? I have also this problem and I would like to rip a curl request but i think I need something like "inspecting a cors requests via curl". The idea is to retrieve this _xmlhttprequests_ from cores requests which you have normally in you browser inspecting it with dev tool. The sits all this media stream links.